# Crosswalk Native interface - cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Tags: cordova, plugins, webview

I Have a method in my LoginActivity and I need to call it from Javascript. I tried add the AddJavascriptInterface but it doesn't seems to work. I can't find how to do it and I stuck with this problem.
I'am using cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.
Cordova Version 5.1.1.
The LoginActivity class extends from CordovaActivity.
Thanks

Code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends CordovaActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadUrl("file://android_assets/www/index.html");

        ((XWalkView) appView
                     .getEngine()
                     .getView())
                     .addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(),
                                            "NativeInterface");

    }

}
```

In index.html, when I use console.log(); NativeInterface is not defined but _cordovaNative is which is implemented inside XWalkWebViewEngine class.

Comment: You say "it doesn't ... work". Can you be more specific? It's much easier to answer when you are very specific about what you've tried, what you expected, and what happened instead. Some of the tips in [Creating a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help you.

Comment: Sorry RJ, I added more details.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the anwser. After two days stuck with it.
Methods inside JsInterface class should be annotated with @org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface not @JavascriptInterface.

Who would ever guest that?